# system("pause") not working, can anyone see what I'm missing?

Tags: c++

My program has errors and wont let me compile. The only errors start at system("pause) though but I dont see why I'm having errors because I did it the same as I always do my programs. Can anyone see what might be the issue? heres the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
 //Declarations
     int SIZE = 10;
     int NUMBERS[10];
     int i;
     int j;
     int temp;
 for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
 {
     cout << "Please enter a number: " << endl;
     cin >> NUMBERS[i];
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
 {
     for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
     {
         if (NUMBERS[j] > NUMBERS[j+1])
         {
           temp = NUMBERS[j];
           NUMBERS[j] = NUMBERS[j+1];             
           NUMBERS[j+1] = temp;
         }
     }
 }
 cout << "Sorted List" << endl;
 cout << "===========" << endl;
 for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
     cout << "Number " << i + 1 << ": " << NUMBERS[i] << endl;
 }

   system("pause");
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: your last `for` has a closing brace, but no opening brace.

Comment: Aggieboy is right, but in the future be sure to post exactly what errors you're getting (though good job on posting where they're from).

Comment: :My program has errors" is not a problem description unless you tell us what those "errors" are - you have that information right in front of you, so there's absolutely no excuse for not sharing it with us. If you learn to properly format your code, pairing opening and closing braces would show you where the problem is located.

Comment: My bad the error just states: [Error] expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token

Comment: BTW since you are using `system("pause")` you are most likely using MS Visual Studio. If so, select your code (Ctrl+A) and format it automatically (Alt+F8).

Answer (score 2):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                             // ^^^ add this missing bracket
     cout << "Number " << i + 1 << ": " << NUMBERS[i] << endl;
 }
^^^  // closing bracket, but has no opening match
```

Of course you can skip braces in this case ( as there is only one single line in for body) so this is also solution:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
     cout << "Number " << i + 1 << ": " << NUMBERS[i] << endl;
```

Comment: Alternatively, remove both braces!

Comment: Note that Aggieboy's suggestion is valid, but only works with one line statements (including this since I'm assuming OP is new to c/c++).